# Generated database field with migrations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two float fields: `fieldA` and `fieldB`. I would like to store in DB float field `fieldC`, which will always have value: `fieldA` * `fieldB`.

I would like to achieve that with migrations. This is what I tried

`$table->float('fieldC', 12, 2)->storedAs('fieldA * fieldB');`

and

`$table->float('fieldC', 12, 2)->storedAs('MULTIPLY(fieldA, fieldB)');`

Both didn't work. Errors are `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fieldA'` and `General error: 1901 Function or expression 'MULTIPLY()' cannot be used`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel migrations dosn't support that. But you can make trigger with raw statement.
Something like that:

```
DB::unprepared("
    DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON tableName FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF old.fieldA <> new.fieldA OR old.fieldB <> new.fieldB THEN
        UPDATE tableName SET fieldC=fieldA+fieldB WHERE id=new.id;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
");
```

You can make it more simple using Laravel model

```
<?php
class YourModel extends Model {
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::saving(function($model){
            $model->fieldC = $model->fieldA + $model->fieldB;
        });
    }
}
```